# Cannot connect to VPN

Tags: vpn

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS but am not able to connect to my school VPN following the instructions [here](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/admin-services/ict/self-service/connect-communicate/remote-access/virtual-private-network-vpn/)

I get a connection failed message some seconds after turning the VPN on[image]

I am able to make it work on Windows and on the same WiFi so it's not a matter of wrong passwords or blocked access. Could someone assist?

Here are the steps I took.
Install `network-manager-pptp` following the guide here https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/network-manager-pptp

```
(base) haziq@haziq-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt-get update -y
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done

(base) haziq@haziq-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt-get install -y network-manager-pptp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-pptp is already the newest version (1.2.8-2).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 49 not to upgrade.
```

Install `network-manager-pptp-gnome` https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/network-manager-pptp-gnome

```
(base) haziq@haziq-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt-get update -y
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

(base) haziq@haziq-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo apt-get install -y network-manager-pptp-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-pptp-gnome is already the newest version (1.2.8-2).
network-manager-pptp-gnome set to manually installed.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 49 not to upgrade.
```

There is a lot of output from the logs so here they are. I ran the command then immediately turned on the VPN and copy pasted the output up until I got the connection failed message.

```
(base) haziq@haziq-Lenovo-Z580:~$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-11-19 01:36:38 GMT. --
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723877.6468] audit: op="connection-deactivate" uuid="8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50" name="Imperial College VPN" pid=12057 uid=1000 result="success"
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 dbus-daemon[884]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12076]: Terminating on signal 15
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12076]: Terminating on signal 15
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12076]: Child process /sbin/pptp 146.179.63.146 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-12072 (pid 12079) terminated with signal 15
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12076]: Child process /sbin/pptp 146.179.63.146 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-12072 (pid 12079) terminated with signal 15
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 nm-dispatcher[12140]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Dec 23 11:44:37 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723877.6938] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60330,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723881.4891] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50" name="Imperial College VPN" pid=12057 uid=1000 result="success"
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723881.5016] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60120,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 12147
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723881.5106] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60120,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723881.5274] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60120,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723881.5352] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60120,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12151]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: Using interface ppp1
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12151]: Using interface ppp1
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12151]: Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/2
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/2
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723881.5460] manager: (ppp1): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/24)
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-udevd[12134]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12158]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[main:pptp.c:353]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:781]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Dec 23 11:44:41 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:815]: Client connection established.
Dec 23 11:44:42 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Dec 23 11:44:42 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:900]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Dec 23 11:44:42 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:938]: Outgoing call established (call ID 5901, peer's call ID 47104).
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12076]: Connection terminated.
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12076]: Connection terminated.
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 gnome-shell[2370]: Removing a network device that was not added
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12081]: nm-pptp-service-12072 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:226]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12081]: nm-pptp-service-12072 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:238]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12076]: Modem hangup
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12076]: Modem hangup
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12092]: nm-pptp-service-12072 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:245]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12076]: Exit.
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12092]: nm-pptp-service-12072 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Dec 23 11:44:43 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12092]: nm-pptp-service-12072 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call state)
Dec 23 11:44:47 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:44:51 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 systemd-resolved[665]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12151]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12151]: Connection terminated.
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: Connection terminated.
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <warn>  [1608723912.5834] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60120,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723912.5847] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60120,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723912.5850] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60120,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1608723912.5912] vpn-connection[0x5624a8b60120,8606a080-69d2-4f67-afc3-d5c7aff92a50,"Imperial College VPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 gnome-shell[2370]: Removing a network device that was not added
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: Terminating on signal 15
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12151]: Terminating on signal 15
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: Modem hangup
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12151]: Modem hangup
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 NetworkManager[12151]: Child process /sbin/pptp 146.179.1.147 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-12147 (pid 12154) terminated with signal 15
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: Child process /sbin/pptp 146.179.1.147 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-12147 (pid 12154) terminated with signal 15
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pppd[12151]: Exit.
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12158]: nm-pptp-service-12147 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:226]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12158]: nm-pptp-service-12147 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:238]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:245]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Dec 23 11:45:12 haziq-Lenovo-Z580 pptp[12165]: nm-pptp-service-12147 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call state)
```

Comment: Edit your question to tell us what you did, step-by-step, and the result that leads you to believe that it didn't work. Error messages or log entries would also be helpful. Help us to help you.

Comment: 1) have u installed that packages? 2) show us logs `journalctl -f` then try to connect

Comment: image is not logs. Open terminal, then execute `journalctl -f` then try to connect. Copy paste lines that appeared after your attempt to connect

Comment: Why don't you contact your IT support desk for your organization? There is a link on the page you linked.

Comment: I am wondering why for Windows they explain to use OpenVPN, and for Linux they tell you to use PPTP, especially since PPTP is considered outdated and insecure. I would try downloading the OpenVPN config file they propose for Windows and use that with OpenVPN on your Linux box (`openvpn ic.ovpn` on the terminal for starters).